# Not able to access keycloak on kubernetes

Tags: java, docker, kubernetes, dockerfile, keycloak

I am facing a weird issue, my keycloak is running successfully in minikube but at the same time I am not able to access by port forwarding to 8080. I wanted my own spi to be deployed so created a new docker image file as shown below.

```
FROM jboss/keycloak:latest
ADD common-keycloak-spi-0.1.jar /opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/deployments/
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/env"]
CMD ["sh","/opt/jboss/tools/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

Now this runs fine in docker container but when I am trying to depoloy it on kubernetes I am unable to access the service by using port forwading.

```
vipul@vipul-Latitude-5530:~/Downloads$ kubectl port-forward springdoc-64f8dbf547-xrqcl 8080:8080 
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:8080 -> 8080
Forwarding from [::1]:8080 -> 8080
Handling connection for 8080
Handling connection for 8080
E0216 15:24:29.872454   24829 portforward.go:407] an error occurred forwarding 8080 -> 8080: error forwarding port 8080 to pod 5ad97759ea56d8d9acbeecc9dc3cda33bdb0ff138b5c126de37cb7bad985b74f, uid : exit status 1: 2023/02/16 09:54:29 socat[93218] E connect(5, AF=2 127.0.0.1:8080, 16): Connection refused
E0216 15:24:29.873263   24829 portforward.go:233] lost connection to pod
Handling connection for 8080
E0216 15:24:29.874222   24829 portforward.go:345] error creating error stream for port 8080 -> 8080: EOF
vipul@vipul-Latitude-5530:~/Downloads$ kubectl exec springdoc-64f8dbf547-xrqcl -- /bin/bash
```

And also getting NONE for any port and host port in kubectl describe .

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can  check the following step to troubleshoot the issue:

1. Check whether the firewall is blocking the port.  `“netstat -anp | grep 8080”`
2. Check the pod is configured correctly with port and host port in the config yaml file. Use this[link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport-custom-port) as a reference.
3. If you are using the same port configuration in Docker container and in the kubectl will not access the same port so try to check the port number.

Also you can check the blog by [Ales Nosek](https://alesnosek.com/blog/2017/02/14/accessing-kubernetes-pods-from-outside-of-the-cluster/#:%7E:text=are%20connected%20to.-,hostPort,-The) for hostport.